# Extracting URL parameters to update Django app database

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm putting together my first attempt at a Django app and I want to extract parameters from a URL and use them to update the database in a Django app. One page of the app contains a jQuery script that sends out an ajax GET request of the form `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storelatlong/?lng=56.237244700410336&lat=-4.6197509765625` containing user input information as its `lat` and `lng` parameters. I want to retrieve that information and use it to update my `UserProfile.latitude` and `UserProfile.longitude` values stored in my database.

So, I've got two basic questions:

1. How do I get the parameter info into a `views.storelatlong`?
2. Once the information's there, how do I use it to update `models.UserProfile`?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from moddle import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact_us/$', views.contact_us, name='contact_us'),
    url(r'^faq/$', views.faq, name='faq'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/mybookings/$', views.view_bookings, name='view_bookings'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/addbike/$', views.upload_bike, name='upload_bike'),
    url(r'^(?P<bike_id_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.bike_profile, name='bike_profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<bike_id_slug>[\w\-]+)/request/$', views.request_bike, name='request_bike'),
    url(r'^storelatlong/$', views.storelatlong, name='storelatlong'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def user_profile(request, username):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        context_dict['userprofile'] = userprofile
        users_bikes = Bike.objects.filter(owner=userprofile)
        context_dict['bikes'] = users_bikes
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        print "User does not exist"
        context_dict['bikes'] = None
        context_dict['userprofile'] = None
    return render(request, 'MyApp/user_profile.html', context=context_dict)

def storelatlong(request):
    context_dict = {'': ''}
    lat = float(request.GET.get('lat', ''))
    lng = float(request.GET.get('lng', ''))
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
    gender_male = models.BooleanField()
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Currently, sending out the GET request just results in my getting 301 (moved permenantly) and 500 (internal server error) messages in the browser and the following in the command line server:

```
[10/Mar/2017 15:43:28] "GET /storelatlong lng=56.359671608143785&lat=-5.23773193
359375 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /storelatlong/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\MyAppEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",     line 39, in inner response = get_response(request)
  File "H:\MyAppEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
      response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "H:\MyAppEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "H:\MyApp\MyApp_project\MyApp\views.py", line 33, in user_profile user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  File "H:\MyAppEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
   return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\MyAppEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 385, in get self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[10/Mar/2017 15:43:28] "GET /storelatlong/lng=56.359671608143785&lat=-5.23773193359375 HTTP/1.1" 500 18754
```

Thanks in advance for your time and wisdom.

Comment: By which criteria you search for a user? You get an error of `User.DoesNotExist`. Where do you query for the user?

Comment: I don't think I am querying for the user. Where should I do so? And how?

Comment: Let me understand. You somehow have some GET parameters in your url and you want to update a `UserProfile` record with these (new) parameters, right?

Comment: The error is happening in the `user_profile` function, in line 33 of your views. You should show that function.

Comment: Yes. I've got a script that extracts new latitude and longitude coordinates when a user clicks on a map. The script then uses jQuery's `$.ajax({` to send them on to as URL parameters. I want to somehow extract those parameters and use them to update my `UserProfile`. I want this all to happen in the background while the user stays on the same page, which doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `user_profile` added.

Comment: So user_profile is a view? There must be something wrong with your URLs if your request is going there instead of storelatlong. Please show your urls.py.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There you go. Thanks for persevering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django processes URL patterns in order, until it finds one that matches. Unfortunately, your `user_profile` has a pattern which matches any alphanumeric string - which includes "storelatlong". So the user_profile view is being called, and it tries to retrieve the user "storelatlong", which doesn't exist - hence the error.

You could fix this by moving your `storelatlong` pattern above the user_profile one. However, you will have exactly the same problem with your `bike_profile` view - this has exactly the same pattern as `user_profile`, and so there is simply no way for Django to distinguish between them. You should use a prefix or suffix to make the bike_profile pattern unique.